# How to get a variable value from a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a variable from a javascript function, but I am having a problem getting it the variable value outside the function. The variable value can be outputted just fine inside the function. Here is the script, but how can I get the value of status and use it outside the funcion?

```
       <script>
            function get_id(){              
                $('.addressClick').click(function() {
                    var status = $(this).attr('id');
                    alert(status); // Here the value is printed correctly
                    return status;
                });
            }

            var variable = get_id();
            alert(variable);        // Here the valiable isn't outputed

            $("#"+variable).confirm();
    </script>
```

Comment: how do you expect to get the value before the click if the click is what defines the value?

Comment: Thank you for your time,
To tell the truth I don't have knowledge about javacript.
But this was the code that I was able to write to get a least the id of the button that I click. My problem is that I have e table with a list of elements and a delete button that if the user clicks it, it should show a popup confirmation window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, see my example :

```
function get_id(){              
    $('.addressClick').click(function() {
        //...
    });
    return 12;
}

var variable = get_id();
alert(variable); //12
```

'return status;' is in event function and not in get_id function.

The solution is that (don't use global variable if you have big project) :

```
$('.addressClick').click(function() {
    $('.statusSelected').removeClass('statusSelected');
    $(this).addClass('statusSelected');
});
alert($('.statusSelected').attr('id'));

$("#"+variable).confirm();
```